# Do while loop is not stopping even though the condition no longer met

Tags: c#

I have a `do while` loop whose condition depends on a property value of an object. The object looks like this:

```
public class MyObjectType
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public bool IsValid { get; set; }
   public DateTime CompletionTimeStamp { get; set; }
   public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

The `do while` loop looks like this:

```
public Task DoSomething(MyObjectType myObject)
{
   do
   {
      // Call DB get some values
      var someData = _myRepository.Get(myObject.Id);

      // Process data
      someData.SomeValue = SomeFunction(someData.Property1, someData.Property2);

      // Not pretty code but I'm trying to set a few values for myObject here
      if(someData.SomeValue == null)
         MyUtils.PopulateErrorData(ref myObject, "Something went wrong!!!");

      // Save data -- When there's an error, I don't want to this this step
      await _myRepository.Save(someData);
   }
   while(myObject.IsValid);
}
```

The `PopulateErrorData()` function is just a place where I set the values of `myObject`:

```
public static void PopulateErrorData(ref MyObjectType myObject, string comments)
{
    myObject.IsValid = false;
    myObject.CompletionTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    myObject.Comments = comments;
}
```

I can't say that I'm really happy about this approach but in my `DoSomething()` function which is a backend maintenance function, I need to go through a lot of steps and if any of them fails, I want to abort the process.

I figured I can just use a `do while` and when the condition is no longer met, it would kick me out of the loop anyway but it is NOT. It just keeps on going. In the above code, if `someData.SomeValue == null`, I should never save the data but as I said, the code continues and I end up saving data in the database.

Any idea why it doesn't kick me out of the loop even though `myObject.IsValid` is set to `false` by `PopulateErrorData()`?

Comment: Have you verified that the method is called?

Comment: I assume you mean `PopulateErrorData()`. Yes, because I have the other properties with proper values i.e. comments, time stamp, etc.

Comment: I believe you don't need to pass the object by ref. It's already passed on that way by default.

Comment: @JuanR I'm using `ref` so that it comes back. Otherwise, I have to create a new `MyObjectType` inside the `PopulateErrorData()` method and return it. Notice that `PopulateErrorData()` is a `void` function so it doen't return anything which is why I'm sending my object there with a `ref`. That's the part I don't like anyway.

Comment: Please, post content body from `SomeFunction()`method.

Comment: @JuanR No, it's not passed by reference by default, it's passed by value.  It's simply that the value being passed *is a reference*, and the reference is not being changed, and since the variable being passed isn't changing, `ref` is superfluous here.

Comment: Like I said, you don't need to pass the object by ref. Classes are reference types already. There is nothing coming or going. It's a pointer.

Comment: @Sam But you're not mutating the variable that you're passing by reference.  You're just mutating a value that the reference it contains refers to, so you don't need to pass it by reference.  It's a reference type, the variable already contains a reference.

Comment: While there is no need in the code in the question to pass with `ref`, it will have no bearing on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you are saving the data first, then you are checking for `IsValid` property. Just make the code simpler:

```
public Task DoSomething(MyObjectType myObject)
{
   // if myObject.IsValid is set initially, then uncomment the following line.
   // myObject.IsValid = true;
   while(myObject.IsValid)
   {
      // Call DB get some values
      var someData = _myRepository.Get(myObject.Id);

      // Process data
      someData.SomeValue = SomeFunction(someData.Property1, someData.Property2);

      // Not pretty code but I'm trying to set a few values for myObject here
      if(someData.SomeValue == null)
         MyUtils.PopulateErrorData(ref myObject, "Something went wrong!!!");

      if(!myObject.IsValid)
          break;

      // Save data -- When there's an error, I don't want to this this step
      await _myRepository.Save(someData);
   }

}
```

Comment: On a different note: as others have mentioned, if `MyObjectType` is a class, you don't need use `ref` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Think you need to change this

```
  // Not pretty code but I'm trying to set a few values for myObject here
  if(someData.SomeValue == null)
     MyUtils.PopulateErrorData(ref myObject, "Something went wrong!!!");

  // Save data -- When there's an error, I don't want to this this step
  await _myRepository.Save(someData);
```

To this

```
  if(someData.SomeValue == null)
  {
     MyUtils.PopulateErrorData(ref myObject, "Something went wrong!!!");
  }
  else
  {
      // Save data -- When there's an error, I don't want to this this step
      await _myRepository.Save(someData);
  }
```

Or

```
  if(someData.SomeValue == null)
  {
     MyUtils.PopulateErrorData(ref myObject, "Something went wrong!!!");
     break;
  }
  // Save data -- When there's an error, I don't want to this this step
  await _myRepository.Save(someData);
```

Although for the life of me I don't understand what purpose is served by a while loop in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

The other upvoted answers show you the changes you need to make, but I want to make sure you know *why* that is so (you seem to be missing a few C# fundamentals).

The conditional of a while loop is *not* evaluated continually. It is only evaluated at the beginning (`while`) or end (`do ... while`) of the loop. Thus setting the flag won't prevent the next statement from occurring. To exit a loop *early* you need a `break` (to exit the loop entirely) or a `continue` (to skip to the next iteration).

Thus the solution is to put your save in an `else`, add a `break` to the existing `if` block, or do the `else` and remove the loop entirely unless you actually want to do this more than once.

You also have an unnecessary `ref`. Classes in C# are already passed as a reference, so changes to their properties will be seen by future users of the same object. The only time you need to use `ref` is if you *actually assign the parameter to something*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! I appreciate it.